# calendar events - 10K recipients limit problem for large events

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, exchange-server, outlook-restapi, microsoft-graph-calendar

Use case:
For online platform integration we want to send invites for events using endpoint
POST /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/events

We handled the limit of 500 attendee by splitting large event to multiple calendar events containing each 500 attendees emails

New problem is 10,000 recipients a day limit

If event has large audience (ex. 100 000 person webinar event) we get blocked after 10K recipients ( 20 calendar events each having 500 attendees)

how to go around this, how to scale calendar events?

Comment: Yes. 10k is the recipient limit set my Exchange on-line and being an online high availability service the limit is set. Here's the [documentation for it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/exchange-online-service-description/exchange-online-limits). What about adding the recipients in a DL/Group and make use of it?

Comment: yes, I seen some advices around the web to go with approach of creating groups. Although it's not optimal and requires quite lot of overhead/maintanance of the groups/lists. If there is a good sdk example how it's mitigated I'm more than happy to have a look.

Comment: The above workaround works. Being said that still you can consider talking to Microsoft support/engineering about your scenario to see if there's anything alternate available from there end as well. If you find anything share it with the community, so it can be useful to others as well.